# Can I recover my funds sent to a non-existent storage address on another network?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I mistakenly sent my Metamask funds from the Ethereum network to the Gnosis vault, but to the ZkSync network
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2ddfc93e7855f88b80183d3bb0a5abdd9122bf78fefc7e9bd0c860a8c672aef6

Can I recover my funds sent to a non-existent storage address on another network?
Perhaps I can access an address that has not yet been created in Gnoziz on the Ethereum network I need

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, zkSync doesn't natively support EVM bytecode, and it's impossible to produce the same address on zkSync.

Answer (score -1):

you can add Zksync rpc on your metamask account to gain access to the wallet address that holds these funds.

Comment: Please tell me how can I do this?
Can I really create a wallet with exactly the address I need on the ZkSink network?

Comment: go to chainlist.org and add the zksync network chain to your metamask. Then click on the add account icon on your metamask tab to add the wallet address that holds your funds.

Comment: The ZkSync network was already on my Metamask
I added several new accounts on it, but the address I need is not there.

Perhaps we misunderstood each other.
Can I go to Metamask and make myself whatever address I want?

Just in case, I’ll clarify, I sent funds from my Metamask on the ETH network to the Gnosis STORAGE to an essentially non-existent account/address on the ZkSync network

Comment: Do you have access to the gnosis vault account? if you do that might be helpful.

Comment: Yes, I have access to my storage, but the storage address on the ZkSync network, as you understand, is not the one I need.

Comment: you can import your Gnosis seeds into metamask and add new addresses. Can you write the storage address here?

Comment: Please tell me where I can get my seed phrase from Gnosis to import into my metamask? 
my storage address 0x9716B618d7E6B26F24fd41e8fa751eF368530BD3